# 2d array giving wrong output

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, output

I was writing a code to print all the strings stored in 2d array after the user has finished typing the strings along with mentioning the maxlength of each string and total number strings (it will finally print the string along with the line number). The problem is that the code actually stores all the strings in the 2d array with one whole line of spacing i.e, one full empty row. The code, expected output and the output it is giving is below.

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char s[20][30];
    int i, number_of_strings, length_of_string, j = 0;
    scanf("%d %d", &number_of_strings, &length_of_string);

    for (i = 0; i<number_of_strings; i++) {
        while ((s[i][j++] = getchar()) != '\n' && j<length_of_string)
            s[i][j] = '\0';
        j = 0;
    }

    for (i = 0; i<number_of_strings; i++) {
        printf("i= %d   %s\n", i, s[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Sample Input:**

```
2 3
raj
jar
```

**Expected Output:**

```
i= 0   raj
i= 1   jar
```

**Output giving:**

```
i= 0   

i= 1   raj
i= 2    

i= 3   jar
```

Please rectify where am I doing mistake.

Comment: Is it homework and you have to do this with `getchar`? `fgets` would be better.

Comment: no it's not a homework, i am just comfortable with getchar

Comment: your while loop looks weird.... when `getchar()` returns `\n`..then what?

Comment: Do you realize you have a newline stuck in your input buffer after you second `int` read ? what do you suppose that does to your first loop iteration ?

Comment: You need to eat the `\n` before it consumes in your next iteration.

Comment: `scanf("%d %d", &number_of_strings, &length_of_string);` leaves the `\n` of `2 3\n` in the buffer and the first `getchar()` reads it.

Comment: `while ((s[i][j++] = getchar()) != '\n' && j<length_of_string)
            s[i][j] = '\0';` ==> size test first as `(j + 1) <length_of_string`

Comment: @WhozCraig the newline printing is the problem

Comment: @KaustavBhattacharjee `\n` is in your buffer. This is the problem.

Comment: @KaustavBhattacharjee the printing isn't the problem. your loop is banking on that newline *following* your n-character string; the first one it encounters *doesn't*. The first one encountered it the one remaining in your input stream after your `3` from your sample data. The rest is just an effect after that cause.

Comment: Just do one `getchar()` before your first loop.

Comment: @jackjay and pray the fiend at the keyboard didn't type a space after the second `int` and before the newline? c'mon. we can do better than *that*.

Comment: Ofcourse, we can. @WhozCraig

Comment: So now you can easily use `fgets`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've hit [one of the many issues with `scanf`](http://c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). In this case `scanf("%d %d", ...)` is leaving a newline on the buffer. You can get it to slurp in trailing whitespace with a space on the end.

```
scanf("%d %d ", &number_of_strings , &length_of_string);
```

Then how you're reading a line is complicated. You can simplify it like so:

```
 int c, j;
 for(j = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; j++ ) {
     s[i][j] = (char)c;
 }
 s[i][j] = '\0';
```

Or even simpler...

```
for(int i=0 ; i<number_of_strings ; i++) {
    scanf("%29s", s[i]);
}
```

And there's no need for `length_of_string`. In fact, it's a liability since you've only allocated 30 bytes max. Similarly, `number_of_strings` can be higher than the allocated 20. It's better to read until input or memory is exhausted.

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int MAX_STRINGS = 20;
const int MAX_LENGTH = 30;
int main(){ 
    char s[MAX_STRINGS][MAX_LENGTH];
    int num_strings;
    for(num_strings = 0; num_strings < MAX_STRINGS ; num_strings++) {
        if( scanf("%29s", s[num_strings]) < 1 ) {
            break;
        }
    }

    for( int i = 0 ; i < num_strings; i++){                                                                               
        printf("i= %d   %s\n",i,s[i]);
    }

    return 0;      
}
```